How to get problem history through Zabbix API
I want to create a report of resolved problems in Zabbix in a period of time, for example, last month. I can fetch only problems "active" or unresolved using the API (problems.get), but I can't get resolved problems.
I can't get the list of resolved problems in the Portal selecting "History" in the "Problems" window, but I can't find how to retrieve those problem cases using the API.

Is there a way to get that data via API? Or maybe via a database query?
Thanks and best regards.

You should use the event.get api.
According to the object definition, you can filter on source :

Possible values:
0 - event created by a trigger;
[cut]

and on value

Possible values if source is set to "event created by a trigger" or "event created on service status update":
0 - OK;
1 - problem.

